# Event listener targeting all elements on filtering method

Tags: javascript, html, filter, addeventlistener

I am having a little trouble building a mock shopping site. When a button is clicked it appends that item to a checkout menu. The button on the checkout menu is supposed to remove the selected element but instead it deletes the whole menu. I have ran a `forEach` and I have tried to append the remove button with the `createElement` method but it doesn't work. I think the problem is that the buttons aren't actually creating separate elements for itself and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function addToCart(btns, cartItem) {

  btns.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        if (shoppingList.indexOf(cartItem) !== -1) {
            return
        }
        else {
            cartMenuItems.innerHTML += `
            <div class=${'menu-items-container'}>
                <img width=150 height=125 src=${cartItem.image}>
                <div class=${'menu-titles-container'}>
                    <h2> ${cartItem.title}</h2>
                    <h3> ${cartItem.price}</h3>
                    <button class=${'menu-btn'}> Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
            shoppingList.push(cartItem)
            cartItemCount.innerText = shoppingList.length;
        }

        const removeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
        removeItem(shoppingList, removeBtn)

        const getTotalOfItems = shoppingList.reduce((acc, current) => {
            return acc + current.price
        }, 0);


        menuTotal.innerText = getTotalOfItems
        return shoppingList
    });

  });
}

function removeItem(shoppingItems, btns) {

    btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let newArr = shoppingItems.filter(item => item.id !== item.id)
        console.log(newArr)
        shoppingList = newArr
        cartMenuItems.innerHTML = newArr
        cartItemCount.innerText = newArr.length
        return newArr
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below in your `removeItem` function will always create a `newArr` element which is empty because you're comparing two values that are the same (item.id). And always return an empty list

```
let newArr = shoppingItems.filter(item => item.id !== item.id)
```

Comment: I understand that but the button should only be affecting the element to which is was clicked. One button is deleting the entire array, and that's where I think the problem is.